# Ruby/Rails : How to remove all the unicode in a string?

Tags: ruby, unicode

I have a lot of records in a legacy database and I need to export that data into a CSV using the ISO-1889-1 format because there are spanish characters.

However, when converting it to utf-8 to iso, it keeps throwing errors of not being able to convert certain characters. ex:

`Encoding::UndefinedConversionError - U+2026 from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1`

this happens at this line in my controller:

`send_data(data.encode("iso-8859-1"), filename: "books_data_#{date}.csv", type: 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present')`

To fix this individual issue I just did `string.gsub!("…", "")`. Is there a more universal way to just remove all unicode in a ruby string? Doing it by hand for each one that appears is not as complete, ugly, and hard to maintain if new unicode characters arise. Just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [String::encode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode)?

```
irb(main):011:0> "Здравствуйте Stack Overflow!".encode("iso-8859-1", undef: :replace, replace: "")
=> " Stack Overflow!"
```